# Flask Route: return JSON and write to database simultaneously

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to Flask so maybe my approach is wrong, but I use one route to write to a sqlite database and return JSON which is then displayed in a table.  The route works as expected, but it is rather slow on the user end because the write to database happens before the JSON is returned.  Writing to the database takes 0.1-0.4 seconds so it is not a huge problem, but it would be nice if I could eliminate that delay.

Below is my route.  I removed the column names in the new_entry, but again the code runs as expected just the timed section is slower than desired.

Note: I tried a bulk insert using add_all, but that was slower than the for loop when I tested it.

````
@app.route('/api/data/<string:from_port>/<string:to_port>/')
def data(from_port,to_port):
    # this calls the cargosmart sailing schedule api and converts the json return into the desired format

    api_url = helpers.get_api_url(int(un_to_int_dict[from_port]),int(un_to_int_dict[to_port]), api_key=SECRETS.get("big_schedules_api_key"))

    df =  helpers.create_df(requests.get(url = api_url
                                             , proxies=SECRETS.get("proxies")
                                            ),scac_dict = scac_dict)

    
    bigitems = [helpers.create_big_item(df[df['Route ID']==i]) for i in df['Route ID'].unique()]
    api_results = {"data":[x.to_dict() for x in bigitems]}

    
    origin_port = from_port
    destination_port = to_port

    current_date = date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
                           
    new_user_entry = user_data(ip_address = request.remote_addr,
                               origin_port = origin_port,destination_port = destination_port,date = current_date)
                           
    db.session.add(new_user_entry)
    
    request_id = max([x[0] for x in  db.session.query(user_data.id).all()])
                           
    new_sailing_entry = [cargosmart_sailings(
                     from_port = df['From Port'].iloc[i],to_port= df['To Port'].iloc[i],terminal = df['To Terminal'].iloc[i],
                     etd = convert_date(df['ETD'].iloc[i]),
                     eta = convert_date(df['ETA'].iloc[i]),
                     vessel_name = df['Vessel Name'].iloc[i],service= df['Service'].iloc[i],
                     external_voyage_number = df['External Voyage Number'].iloc[i],
                     direct = df['Direct'].iloc[i],carrier = df['Carrier'].iloc[i],
                     cutoff = convert_date(df['Cutoff'].iloc[i]),
                     transit_time = df['Transit Time'].iloc[i],
                     request_id = request_id
                     
                    ) for i in range(df.shape[0])]


    for x in new_sailing_entry:

        db.session.add(x)
    db.session.commit()
    
    
    return jsonify(api_results) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see you using `request_id` but that will slow down over time as more entries go into the table.  What you probably want there is

```
db.session.add(new_user_entry)
db.session.commit()

request_id = new_user_entry.id
```

as this will have the assigned id after its committed to db. But its hard to see what your intentions are in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I edited the code so that you can see everything.  I dont think there are any problems with the actual functionality.  I just want to know if I can have the write to database happen after the json is sent to the html because the writing to database is irrelevant to the end user.

Comment: The only way to do that is defer the write to db in a worker thread, which is poping new work off the queue of updates. But then what happens if the commit fails? you have to undo the notification to user?  Meanwhile could `max([x[0] for x in  db.session.query(user_data.id).all()])` slowing down this query?    `db.session.query(func.max(user_data.id))` may shave off cycles by optimizing your db query.

Comment: This new worker thread sounds like just what I want.  If the write fails I still want the user to get the results.  I'll change the find max also. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: in that case checkout BackgroundScheduler which simplifies timed background tasks. https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/94838/apscheduler.schedulers.background.BackgroundScheduler